# Intel XDK Barcode Scanner not working with Cordova Building

Tags: javascript, cordova, barcode, intel-xdk

I created an application with Intel XDK that needs to scan the bar codes. So i used the intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode() method to realize this function. My problem is that the build of my application doesn't work if i build it with Cordova builder. This is my code:

```
function BarcodeScanner() {
    try {
        intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan", function (evt) {
    intel.xdk.notification.beep(1);
    if (evt.success == true) {
        artsel = SearchArticoloByBarcode(evt.codedata);
        DisplayInfoArt();
        ConfArtCheck();
        setTimeout(function () { $.ui.scrollToTop("page4", "200") }, 200);
    }
    else {
        alert("Errore lettura");
    }
}, false);
```

The build is successful, but when I run my app I catch an error that says: "Cannot read property 'scanBarcode' of undefined".
If I build the application with legacy builder the app works, but I'd like to use the other builder because the app created is faster and lighter.
The app works also with the Debugger. For now I'm working with an Android Phone (Nexus 5), but the app should run also on iOS and Windows Phone.

Does someone know something about this issue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guess is you did not include the appropriate xdk plugin from the "plugins" section of the Projects tab. Also, that plugin has been deprecated, we recommend you use a Cordova equivalent.